# Incorrect results appearing when searching for events by date range

Tags: civievent, search

Has anyone else found the "Search All or by Date Range" option in "Manage Events" to return incorrect results, particularly if you have events that have a start date but no end date recorded?

I've filed a bug ([CRM-18250](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18250)) and I think I know where it is, but I'd be interested to know if others are also observing it.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I'll note that [this issue is resolved](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8042) in CiviCRM 4.7.5+.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted this recently, and an issue was added to issues.civicrm.org

I remember coming across this at FF and also logging an issue about it...